# How to get/set caret position relative to HTML in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have

```
 ​<div contenteditable='true'>
 my <b>bold</b> text
 </div>
```

I'd like to get (and set) the cursor position relative to the innerHtml.

But here's the catch, I looked at many answers on StackOverflow and most of them
are dealing with selection objects and ranges and so forth. I don't want
to deal with all that. It's way too difficult. I just want to work with the 
simple InnerHTML string and the index for the cursor.

Say you click on the b of the word 'bold' I just want it to return index of: 6 (meaning it 
would take into account the bold html tag).

I'd also like to be able to say (setCursor(6)) and it'll set the cursor right before the 'bold'.

Comment: That's the only way to get your cursor position though. Sometimes there is no "easier" way :/ Also, what have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: It'll be a whole heap more difficult to get and set a cursor position relative to `innerHTML` representations. Why do you think it will be easy to deal with?

Comment: B/c I just want to insert some text where the cursor is, and I want to set the cursor wherever I want.. I don't want to deal with nodes

Comment: How do you intend to set the cursor where you want? What steps?